# Counting number of iterations before match is found not working right

Tags: python, list

I have the below code:

```
def numbers():
    '''returns 2 random numbers between 1 and 10 that are not the same
    '''
    b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
    res = []
    count = 0
    while len(res) < 2:
        if b not in res:
            res.append(b)
            b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
    return res


def match_count():
    '''counts how many times numbers must be ran before a match is found.
    '''
    count = 0
    a = sorted(numbers())
    b = sorted(numbers())
    while b != a:
        b = sorted(numbers())
        count += 1
        print a, b
    return count
```

When I run this code sometimes count is returned, but the majority of the time the program appears to hang without a match and I have to interrupt it. for example

```
>>> match_count()
[3, 8] [3, 5]
[3, 8] [1, 9]
[3, 8] [1, 4]
[3, 8] [5, 10]
[3, 8] [3, 8]
5
>>> match_count()
[2, 8] [4, 6]
[2, 8] [4, 10]
[2, 8] [1, 3]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#252>", line 1, in <module>
    match_count()
  File "C:\Python27\match_count.py", line 24, in match_count
   b = sorted(numbers())
  File "C:\Python27\match_count.py", line 10, in numbers
    while len(res) < 1:
 KeyboardInterrupt
```

if I change `while len(res) < 2` to `while len(res) < 1` the program works every time. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions on making this code more efficient is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code lines

```
while len(res) < 2:
    if b not in res:
        res.append(b)
        b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
```

run in an infinite loop if first and second number are the same (b is only changes in case its different, otherwise it is an infinite loop). Correct indentation to

```
while len(res) < 2:
    if b not in res:
        res.append(b)
    b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
```

and everything should work correct.

Comment: Hey ... this is absolutely correct but I had this doubt that is there no way we can generate random number from a discontinous range in python directly ? as in selecting from 1-4 and 5-9 ? We can use what you provided but is there any default function for the same..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible problem: the first time through your `while len(res) < 2:` loop, your new value of b could be the same as the old value of b. Then this code will loop forever:

```
while len(res) < 2:
    if b not in res:
        res.append(b)
        b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
```

because `len(res)` will always be 1 and your `if b not in res` test will always fail.

Comment: That makes sense, but what would be a solution to prevent it from entering into an impossible loop? Eventually I would like to increase the number of items in the list.

Comment: Assign a new b if the test fails. That way the next time though the loop will try a different b. Just move `b = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
` one tab stop to the left.